# Calculating electric potential from a changing electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

Assuming that I calculated the electric field in a single point between a uniform charged positive sphere and an infinite long wire charged positive uniformly.
Now, I want to calculate the velocity of a given particle q+ which will be set free from the point (A) which I calculated the field at, while hitting the surface of the sphere.
It is very clear that the electric field will change at any point during the particle q movement, but can I still use the Line Integral of the electric field in point A to calculate the Voltage between point A and the surface of the sphere? or do I need to calculate individualy the potential of the wire and sphere and these 2 points?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line integral would only work for finding a potential difference, which I presume is what you need. Since the line integral needs a path(to perform the integration), hence, it would need a general expression for electric field(in your case, finding the potential requires integrating from $\infty$ to $A$, so you'd need the expression for all points between $\infty$ and $A$).

So, I would suggest calculating the potential at both points and then finding the difference. Please give more details about how you calculated the field at A.

Comment: I have already calculated the field in point A which is 5/9*kQ/R^2. can I use the line integral with this expression even though the electric field probably changes throughout the motion of the particle?

Comment: No, you cannot use this expression, because, in $\int \vec E\cdot d\vec r$ you need the Electric field at "all points in the path", and you have an expression for just a single point.

Comment: Got it, so I will do what you told me, so basicly, the line integral can be used only for parts in which the electric field is constant in them?

Comment: Yes, but for a constant electric field you do not need to integrate at all! Multiplication would suffice(but only for straight paths, as in your case).

Comment: So what is the use of the integral? in which situations will I be needed to use it? I don't see how it help in any situation...

Comment: As an example, if you calculated the expression for electric field at a general point in your problem, you could use the line integral to find the potential difference between any two points. Also, it is better to have a basic definition, in case the reference potential is changed, or the potential is not defined at infinity, e.g., for a line charge, etc.